# C++11 decltype: How to declare the type that a pointer points to?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    int* a = new int(2);

    std::unique_ptr<decltype(*a)> p(a);
}
```

which leads to these error message:

```
In file included from a.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/memory:81:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/unique_ptr.h:138:14: error: '__test' declared as a pointer to a reference of type 'int &'
          static _Tp* __test(...);
                    ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/unique_ptr.h:146:35: note: in instantiation of member class 'std::unique_ptr<int &,
      std::default_delete<int &> >::_Pointer' requested here
      typedef std::tuple<typename _Pointer::type, _Dp>  __tuple_type;
                                  ^
a.cpp:7:35: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::unique_ptr<int &, std::default_delete<int &> >' requested here
    std::unique_ptr<decltype(*a)> p(a);
                                  ^
In file included from a.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/memory:81:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/unique_ptr.h:227:33: error: 'type name' declared as a pointer to a reference of type 'int &'
               is_convertible<_Up*, _Tp*>, is_same<_Dp, default_delete<_Tp>>>>
                                       ^
a.cpp:7:35: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::unique_ptr<int &, std::default_delete<int &> >' requested here
    std::unique_ptr<decltype(*a)> p(a);
                                  ^
2 errors generated.
```

I understand the reason is that the unique_ptr template expects type `int`, but `decltype(*a)` gives `int&`. In the case that `int` is a very long and complicated type, how can I make this code work with decltype?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<std::pointer_traits<decltype(a)>::element_type> p(a);`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`std::decay_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay). This is the conversion that is applied when you pass an argument to a function by value.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<std::decay<decltype(*a)>::type> p(a);` works!

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<std::decay_t<decltype(*a)>> p(a);` for C++14, `std::unique_ptr<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*a)>> p(a);` also works.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a typedef inside a templated class and then use template specialisation, like this

```
template<typename T> struct unref {
  typedef T raw;
};
template<typename T> struct unref<T&> { 
  typedef T raw;
};

int main() {
    int* a = new int(2);
    std::unique_ptr<unref<decltype(*a)>::raw> p(a);
}
```

Comment: You need to add `*struct* unref` and a you missed a semicolon after the second template definition.

Comment: In C++11, there exists std::remove_reference.

Comment: @cbel Certainly, and before C++11 there were boost utilities to do the same. This was more a "teach a man to fish" type answer...